# Multi-array number generation

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, c++

This part of my project is very hard for my brain to wrap around and comprehend. But basically I just need to go through every combination. For example:

If I have an array with 255 variables and I need to bruteforce all the combinations by 30's (0, 30, 60, 90) How would I go about doing that in a decently compact form? It's really brain hurting please help a noob out <3

Note: I'm making a universal IR Remote but if by chance I don't have the code then I can just change the mode to brute force it.

```
volatile uint16_t IRCode[]={384,171,43,21,21,21,21,21,21,64,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,64,21,21,21,64,21,21,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,64,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,21,21,64,21,64,21,64}; // ProntoHex to uint16_t delete first 4 array numbers.
volatile uint16_t MicrosPassed;
volatile uint8_t ArraySeq;
uint8_t LEDState;
uint8_t SetMode=0;

void setup() {
  Config();
  SendIRCode();
}

void loop() {

}

void SendIRCode() {
  if(LEDState==1) {
    TCCR1A&=63;
    LEDState=0;
  } else {
    TCCR1A|=192;
    LEDState=1;
  }
}

void Config() {
  DDRB|=10;
  ICR1=416;
  OCR1A=9983;
  TCCR1A=2;
  TCCR1B=24;
  TCCR1B|=1;
  TIMSK1=1;
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
  MicrosPassed++;
  if(MicrosPassed==IRCode[ArraySeq]) {
    SendIRCode();
    MicrosPassed=0;
    ArraySeq++;
       }
}
```

Comment: this is a general programming question that is not arduino specific

Comment: examine the use of `for` loops

Comment: @jstola it is 100% arduino-uno specific. Config() is for arduino-uno made in the arduino ide. random() is a arduino function. If I did config() on anything but the uno it would most likely not work.

Comment: @fman122: your Config function is plain AVR C code. The only Arduino flavor is the fact that you have a setup and loop function rather than a main (or some other entry point) - and you're not using any Arduino functions in there either.

Comment: @Mat well I mean if you read the post instead of arguing I was planning on using a arduino function called random(). That's why I mentioned it. Why does everyone try to delete other peoples questions :| I've seen so many great questions on here and people always close them for stupid reasons and assume things about the post even if they are obvious. Also again if I did my specific sketch I would not be able to run it on anything other than a arduino. It makes literally no sense to go to any other forum. Arduino doesn't contain all of c/c++ so it would be dumb to go to another forum asking abou

Comment: infrared communication on a arduino uno on a forum about electronics, or programming. But I sha'll try that and see what result I get and update you. ;) HINT: (They will either close it or tell me to go to the arduino stack exchange).

Comment: What do you mean by "all the combinations by 30's"? Do you mean any possible combination of 30 elements out of the 255?

Comment: Not sure why you doing this? there are library exist that you could use, or learn from. You may want to take a look at [Arduino-IRremote](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote) which was based on a c-library long existed even before Arduino was invented. Take a look at the [IRsendRawDemo](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/examples/IRsendRawDemo/IRsendRawDemo.ino) example, and the library source code.

Comment: In my opinion the question is on topic. It asks for Arduino solution of a problem. and then chrisl's and hcheung's comments apply

Comment: @chrisl I meant by counting by 20's. So 20,40,60. I found that you can skio microseconds and just jump and it will most likely work.

Comment: @hcheung 1. I get a better grasp learning something through analysis and the inner workings. 2. the project I am working towards can't have a single bug. So I'm keep it simple barebones and tight. Not even an emp will be able to mess with the electronics.

Comment: You still didn't really explain what combinations you want to go through. What does counting by 20s mean here (and why now 20s, not 30s like in your question)? Do you want to create an array, where multiples of 20 are randomly stored?